# "stable or volatile function is used as if it is immutable" warning in Postgresql function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgresql function in which there is only a SELECT statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_test()
RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE size INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO size FROM tab;
    RETURN size;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

When I call the function with:

```
SELECT fun_test()
```

Although the result are correct, there will be a warning too:

```
WARNING:  A stable or volatile function is used as if it is immutable
HINT:  The function should be declared as stable or volatile in create function statement.
```

I found in Postgresql document that STABLE is a appropriate selection for functions whose results depend on database lookups, parameter variables (such as the current time zone), etc. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createfunction.html

My question is where the warning comes from? It seems that I am doing what the document requires to do. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I am using postgresql server 8.2.15 
The whole story:

```
CREATE TABLE algo.chengb_tmp
(
userid INT,
username varchar(100)
)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION algo.chengb_fun_test()
RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE size INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO size FROM algo.chengb_tmp;
    RETURN size;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;

SELECT algo.chengb_fun_test()
```

cheng

Comment: Are you linking to the outdated version 8.2 by accident or is that your actual version? If so, start by upgrading to a more recent version. [8.2 has reached its end-of-life in Dec 2011.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Comment: Yes, I am using the version 8.2.15. Is this warning erased in higher versions?

Comment: I can't promise that the warning is going away with a current version, but chances are it will. If your update of the question shows the whole story now, I can at least guarantee that the same setup did not raise a warning on my 9.1.4 installation. Can't test on 8.2, because ... I don't have one any more of course. If you are stuck with version 8.2, at least upgrade to latest available minor release, like it is recommended: 8.2.23. But rather install 9.1. It is so much better on every level.

Comment: So this is properly answered, right?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, your question does not show the whole story. I tested your function in PostgreSQL 9.1 and it works for me, as expected. No warning.

Possible explanations include:

- A RULE on SELECT on the involved table `tab` that calls another function. (There are no triggers for SELECT)
- A bug in the outdated PostgreSQL version 8.2.15, which might go away with an upgrade.
- You over-simplified the question and abstracted the actual cause of the problem away.

Add more details in the question: your Version of PostgreSQL, the complete definition of table `tab`, the complete error message and its context.

---

As an aside, could be simplified:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_test()
RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$
BEGIN
   RETURN
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

Ore even:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_test()
RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$
   SELECT count(*) FROM tab;
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

But that's probably not the point here.